# Why would it be "convenient" for Luke to die on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

When Luke and Han are en route to the Sarlacc pit, they have the following exchange:

> HAN:
>   I think my eyes are getting better. Instead of a big dark blur, I see a 
>   big light blur.
>
> LUKE:
>   There's nothing to see. **I used to live here, you know.**
>
> HAN:
>   **You're gonna die here, you know. Convenient.**
>
> LUKE:
>   Just stick close to Chewie and Lando. I've taken care of everything.

Why did Han think would be "Convenient" for Luke to die on the same planet in which he used to live? The obvious reason would be if he was going to be buried by his family, but Luke had no family remaining on Tatooine, and it seems unlikely anybody would be dragging his digested remains up from the Sarlacc's stomach. So what did Han mean by this line?

Edit: I understand that Han is being sarcastic, i.e. he's facetiously finding the "bright side" of their impending doom. But finding convenience in Luke's location of death just feels like a complete non-sequitur to me. In other words, *I don't get the joke* and I was hoping there was some explanation.

Comment: Presumably less convenient and more ironic

Comment: Yes, a little gallows humor.

Comment: I understand that Han is being sarcastic, i.e. he's facetiously finding the "bright side" of their impending doom. But finding *convenience* in Luke's location of death just feels like a complete non-sequitur to me.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is really much to it, other than Han being sarcastic.

However, if you really want to reach for an answer, there are certainly reasons why dying on the planet where Luke had lived most of his life would be "convenient."  It would be easy to organize a memorial service, with many of Luke's old friends close by.  If there were a corpse left behind (like if Luke ended up getting shot while trying to escape, rather than being tossed in the Pit of Carkoon and digested by the all-powerful Sarlacc), they wouldn't have to transport it a long way for burial.